# Expectation of the maximum fn

Tags: probability

I am unable to compute the expectation and get the answer in the proper format.Please help!
Let $\tilde{s}_i$ be independently and normally distributed each with mean $0$. Let  $\tilde{s}_i^+ = \max(\tilde{s}_i,0)$ and $\tilde{s}_i^- = \max(-\tilde{s}_i,0)$. Also, 
$\tilde{S}^+ = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \tilde{s}_i^+$ and $\tilde{S}^- = \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \tilde{s}_i^-$ .    I need to show that $$E(\max(\tilde{S}^+,\tilde{S}^-))=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^k E|\tilde{s}_i|+\frac{1}{2}E |\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \tilde{s}_i| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sigma_i+\sqrt{\sum\limits_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2}) .$$ where $\sigma_i$ is the standard deviation of $\tilde{s}_i$.

Comment: For the first identity, the only things to know are that $|x|=x^++x^-$ and $x=x^+-x^-$ and that $\max(s,s')=\frac12(s+s')+\frac12|s-s'|$. For the second, that $E[|z|]=\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$ for every centered normal random variable $z$ with variance $\sigma^2$.

Comment: Got something from the comment above?

Comment: yup :) .. thank you very much.. I am quite new to stackexchange and couldn't see the notifications !

Comment: If you reached a solution, you are encouraged to write it down and post it as an answer to your own question. After a while, you could accept this answer.